# Workaround mutually exclusive "UseShellExecute" and "RedirectStandardOutput"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, perl

I need a workaround that will have the same effect as using True on both of the mutually exclusive UseShellExecute and RedirectStandardOutput.
The reason I need this is because I want to execute my perl script as I would through a CMD.exe:

```
perl perlcompare.pl <file1> <file2> <file3>
```

Noting that putting "perl" in front there seems to be optional as the file is already a .pl file.

I would like to have access to output the run gives me, as there might be error messages that are important to the user (e.g. missing files). Is there another way to achieve this?

```
    Dim myProcess As New System.Diagnostics.Process
    myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "K:\Engineering\Temp\perl"
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "perlcompare.pl"
    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = """" & MasterFile & """" & " " & """" & MasterOutput & """" & " " & """" & ComparisonsOutput & """"
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    myProcess.Start()

    Dim sOutput As String
    Using ProcessStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput
        sOutput = ProcessStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using

    MessageBox.Show(sOutput)   'txtOutput being the output textbox.
```

Quite new to the language and learning, so I will hound any clues you have for me.

Comment: That `myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments` looks horrible.

Comment: @simbabque: Visual Basic is a horrible language. There is no variable interpolation, and you escape a double quote by doubling it up. Also, the concatenation operator is ampersand `&`. All that makes the mess you see, although `"""" & " " & """"` could be just `""" """`. It's best to use `String.Format` which is VB's `sprintf`.

Comment: @Borodin a loooong time ago I bought a Visual Basic 5 _Einsteiger Edition_ box for about 200 DM and hacked on it. That was shortly after I had learned Quick Basic, and before I picked up my first Perl book. However, I still consider it ugly. :)

Comment: @simbabque: You had a misspent youth like the rest of us! Microsoft infuriate me with their VB and C# that are meant not to advance programming technology but to lock people in to their products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why you want to set `UseShellExecute` to *true*. It needs to be *false* to allow redirection of the standard IO channels

If the location of the perl compiler executable is in PATH then you can just set `FileName` to `perl`. It's also better to use `String.Format` to build strings out of variables rather than use all those escaped quotes and concatenations

```vb
Dim myProcess As New System.Diagnostics.Process
myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "K:\Engineering\Temp\perl"
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "perl"
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(
        "perlcompare.pl ""{0}"" ""{1}"" ""{2}""",
        MasterFile,
        MasterOutput,
        ComparisonsOutput)
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
myProcess.Start()
```

If the location of the perl compiler isn't in the PATH then you can just put a fully-qualified file path into `FileName`

Comment: Agreed.  If you want to capture output, you need to turn on Redirection.  To execute a simple Perl script, you don't need to use the system shell, although you might need to specify the full path to Perl or setup other variables.